# Lime Video SDK - Windows10 quick sync config

Tags: c#, video, windows-10

I compiled fine the Samples in Lime Video SDK. On a Windows 7 system works very well but I got error message in a Windows 10 system.

```
"You are not properly configured for either: A) GPU/IGP Quick Sync B) Software fallback
You may not continue until you fix one option for Quick Sync coding
Press a key to exit"
```

I don't know what is the problem. I dug the source but not found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This message simply means that you have not installed the correct Intel HD graphics driver for your OS/CPU combination, or libmfxsw64.dll/so cannot be found in the DLL path, which is the software emulation fallback.

Without the correct device driver or the software fallback DLL/so being loadable, the samples will not be able to run.

What’s the best way to be sure you have drivers setup correctly?
Use either or both of: “MediaSDK System Analyzer“ or ffmpeg with the “-vcodec h264_qsv” option. Sorry for slow response, just noticed this.